# How to extract tar file in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, tar

As titled. I want to use some command, like for .zip files I can say

> unzip myfiles.zip -d mydirectory

But is there a thing for .tar file on Mac as well?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Yes, you can run:

```
tar -xvf myfile.tar
```

For .tar.gz, you can run:

```
tar -xzvf myfile.tar.gz
```

If you want to extract to any directory other than your cwd, use -C. e.g:

```
tar -xvf myfile.tar -C somedirectory
```

I suggest you read the man page for tar if you wish to do anything further:

```
man tar
```

Comment: One option that I'll point out since it may be common is the ability to strip parent directories with `--strip=1`. If you need to "flatten" out the extracted files to aid with automation, play with this and see if it will help.